# Is the search feature not working well on TeX.SX?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I'm facing a strange problem with the search function.

It seems that it finds threads till December 20th but not over that date.

For example, today I've answered this question: [looking for Latex editor with good structure tree layout view that can handle verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152083/27635), which contains the word "texmaker" in its body, but if you make a search for the word "texmaker", the last found is this one: [How to change the color scheme to make this figure more elegant?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150843/27635).

Does anyone know what it is happening?

Comment: Related: [How often are posts indexed for searching?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214716/168244)

Comment: @Werner thanks for the follow-up question on Meta.SO. I seem to remember that before the recent changes on the site, I was able to find things with a delay of about one day... But I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Werner It seems that the problem is solved and the answer in the above post is the answer to my question, too. Please post a link to that post as an answer.

Comment: I experienced that one can not found the query related post from stack exchange. Therefore there may be more duplicate questions. Searching algorithm/mechanism used for it may be weaker than google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[A similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214716/168244) was posted on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), which revealed the following:

> Ok so those indexing times are correct, this was a different issue. You may have noticed before the holidays that TeX was read-only for the better part of a day while I did some very fun database maintenance. For some reason I can't explain (it predates me working for Stack), TeX and its meta (and *only* those) databases had a case insensitive collation. Changing that is somewhat of a pain in the ass, hence the read-only mode for a while.
>
> Doing that caused some other ripples with search that needed a fresh indexing pass (from scratch) to really fix. That has just been performed. It should operate correctly going forward.

Since then, the problem seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 7):

The full-text search has to be indexed, otherwise it would overload the servers and they wouldn't do anything else. The index has to be updated only from time to time since it has to be re-structured and almost re-built from scratch to get it as efficient as possible, and this takes a lot of time.

Therefore I think that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Google is a bit faster in indexing, so you might use it's `site:` feature: 
`site:tex.stackexchange.com texmaker`

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're right. But I seem to remember that it was very much faster before the latest changes on the site.